# Use google images to retrieve urls instad of images

Tags: c#

Hi there is a google page http://www.google.com/imghp where we can load image and search the internet if it exist on some pages, my question is how to do it from c# but not to get all images similar or sth, only pages where this image exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, the way to do that was with Google's [Image Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/), but it is now deprecated and won't be around much longer.  You can still use it while it lasts.

As an alternative, there is Microsoft's [Bing API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251072.aspx), with the [Image SourceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250942.aspx).

**Edit:** From the [link I posted above](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/):

> The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated **as of May 26, 2011**. It will continue to work as per our [deprecation policy](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/terms.html), but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited.

From the [deprecation policy](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/terms.html), section 1.3:

> ... For a period of **three years** after an announcement (the "Deprecation Period"), Google will use commercially reasonable efforts to continue to operate the Deprecated Version of the Service ...

So, you can expect the Google Image Search API to be around until May 26, 2014.  You can enjoy it still for a couple of years.

Comment: so it won't be possible? do u know since when? i don't wanna use bing either tinEye, google is the best.

Comment: @kosnkov - I've updated my answer with a bit more detail on Google's deprecation policy as it relates to the Image Search API's deprecation timeline.

Comment: how can i use it to look for similiar image based on url of my image?

Answer (score 1):

Use TinEye:

https://www.tineye.com/commercial_api

https://api.tineye.com/documentation